# Merging non NaN values values only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table which only includes one value per row and then repeats the same index for each variable. Here is the code and the df output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame([[1.0,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],[np.NaN,6.0,np.NaN,np.NaN],[np.NaN,np.NaN,11.0,np.NaN],[np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,16]],columns=['A','B','C','D'])
df.index=['01-Jan-2021','01-Jan-2021','01-Jan-2021','01-Jan-2021']

Date        A    B      C     D
01-Jan-2021 1.0  NaN    NaN   NaN
01-Jan-2021 NaN  6.0    NaN   NaN
01-Jan-2021 NaN  NaN    11.0  NaN
01-Jan-2021 NaN  NaN    NaN   16.0
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to merge and get this result...

```
Date        A    B     C     D
1-Jan-2021  1.0  6.0   11.0  16.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need first non missing value use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df.groupby('Date').first()
```

If there is only one value per column and group same ouput is if aggrregate `mean`, `max`, `min`, `sum`:

```
df.groupby('Date').sum()

df.sum(level='Date')
```